# Java pi4j app crashes on exit()

Tags: gpio, pigpio, pi4j

My java app runs fine until I execute a System.exit(). I'm using pi4j/pigpio-2.2.1 on a Pi4b with latest raspian OS. I use DigitalOutput to define my own DigitalOutputPin and I2C for some Sparkfun QWIC buttons that also have a self contained LED. The code all works fine but crashes on exit. From the dump file it sppears to be happening in the native C code for pigpio. I've added a few lines from the dump file.

Comment: Here is top of core file:

Comment: # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x6c43f028, pid=6988, tid=8931
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.16+8) (build 11.0.16+8-post-Raspbian-1deb11u1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11.0.16+8-post-Raspbian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, g1 gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libpigpio.so.1+0x23028]
#
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Comment: Current thread (0x70f28800):  JavaThread "pi4j-shutdown" [_thread_in_native, id=8931, stack(0x6b42e000,0x6b47e000)]

Stack: [0x6b42e000,0x6b47e000],  sp=0x6b47c890,  free space=314k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libpigpio.so.1+0x23028]
C  0x6b47ca50

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved the problem. The problem with the I2C is that the reserved id "my-i2c-bus" can be applied only once to a Pi4J Context. Using a new instance of the Context for each I2C device solves that problem. This is not a problem with DigitalOutput since I set the id to "PINn" where n is the pin number. Pi4J doesn't seem to mind that. I think the real problem is that I had a polling loop in a separate Thread running and I wasn't giving it time to stop polling before I do a shutdown(). All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the IO are still in use while shutting down the application. Are you able to call `pi4j.shutdown();` before the program exits?

Comment: It's not clear to me if your pi4j is a static (couldn't find it). What import is used? I do a  Context _pi4j = Pi4J.newAutoContext();several times in my application and if I do _pi4j .shutdown() for each it still crashes.

Comment: See https://pi4j.com/getting-started/minimal-example-application/. You should have only one pi4 contextj, and reuse it throughout your application.

Comment: OK,  I fixed it so there is one pi4j for the entire app. The problem is that I have two DIgital Outputs (each with different addresses) and six I2C buttons with LEDs (with different devices). While your suggestion seems to fix the crash it refuses to create the object to do the IO because keywords already exist from the first instantiation.  I need to be able to change the device or address parameters before I do the create. I haven't found a way around this.. It all works fine with a unique pi4j for each. It just crashes then. Besides the crash, all failures occur on the create(config) call.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the code... I think there is somewhere a problem with the initialization of the single pi4j context and how it is reused within the application.

Comment: the code is part of a large application. If there were a better way of getting the code to you I could send the appropriate pieces. But a little more detail.  The second call of the I2C  code resulted in an error that I could only have one "my-i2c-bus". If I separate the "unchanging" Context, Builder and Provider setting the device and rebuilding just before the "Create()" it  fails probably because I have to do _builder.device(nAddr).build().  Right now I'm trying to figure out what I changed that it can't find the "main()" class.. I doesn't even get started.

Comment: Here's what I get if I use the pi4j context more than once      com.pi4j.io.exception.IOAlreadyExistsException: IO instance [my-i2c-bus] already exists in the Pi4J runtime cont
ext; unable to create a new instance using this reserved id.
com.pi4j.provider.impl.ProviderProxyHandler.invoke(ProviderProxyHandler.java:97)